# What is this plant and how to eradicate it if possible?

Tags: weeds

[image]

This kind of flower is everywhere in my garden.

First of all I would like to know what is it. If I dig it up, it usually has a bulb shape root.

It is literally everywhere in my garden. Is there any easy and eco-friendly way to remove them?

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see a flower that is fully open, but given the existing photo it looks like Star of Bethlehem ([see wiki description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornithogalum_umbellatum)). As you say it is a persistent bulb that once established is hard to get rid of. It does respond to herbicides but so do many other things respond to the same herbicide so that is not the preferred way to go. The more eco friendly way is to become expert in recognizing the emerging plant and being even more persistent than it is. Try to find or build yourself a tool like a forked snake's tongue on a long handle so that you can jab it and sever it just below soil surface. It can spread without flowering and setting seed, but will do so much more slowly if you can deny it the benefit of sunshine on the leaves. After a few days of experience you will become expert at recognizing the young emerging plant, so will be able to remove it from the yard over a period of a few years as the remaining bulbs exhaust themselves trying to re-grow. If you can find an alternate way of denying the leaves any light such as old tin cans or plates or stones then that will do as well, but learn to get them very early as soon as they emerge.